# Creating MD5 for all the rows in the table

Tags: sql-server

I am working on creating a unique key to find the rows that are changed after the last refresh in the table. So my approach here is to take the PK in the table and also create a md5 column for each row and based on PK and md5, check to see if any of the rows in the table have changed since last time.

What is the best method to create md5 in MS SQL based on query itself? that will take care of all the datatype and null columns also.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "delta" in this context? I can't imagine comparing the PK and the MD5 of the PK will yield anything useful.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine how a hash could be used to calculate a delta between two rows.

Comment: Delta mean the table data will change everyday and I want to just see the rows that are change after each refresh rather than checking the whole table.

Comment: So, like... why not use [`ROWVERSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or a trigger to an audit table? Or, add a column for `last updated datetime` that's updated when that row is inserted and updated. With the hash, you'd know that something changed, but not *what* changed... so is it even that useful? [`HASHBYTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is what you are looking for, but I think this is the wrong approach.

Comment: If you must do this within Tsql then use hashbytes - see link below for reference on using hashbytes. I use the github SSIS add-on called MultipleHash and do it in SSIS.  I would also caveat BIG TIME using MD5 as it will produce false positives due to its primitive hashing algorythm.  The only thing worse than MD5 is CRC32. Therefore I would recommend using a more sophisticated hash.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017